# How can I edit a word in the dictionary in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

I would like to edit word in the dictionary in Dragon NaturallySpeaking. Right now I delete it and create a new entry. Is there any way to edit the word directly instead?

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: What do you mean by "Editing" a word? Correcting a spelling?

Comment: @user99572isfine Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazingly, it is not possible to edit a word in the dictionary in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either double-click the word or select it and click Properties, then edit the "Printed Form" to display the way you would like.

Comment: Thanks. Which version of Dragon NaturallySpeaking do you use? I don't see any "printed form".